# .NET Core 3.0 AutoMapper how to provide arguments in mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

In earlier versions of you could provide arguments in a mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(res => res.Context.Options.Items["Foo"]));
```

at runtime:

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => opt.Items["Foo"] = "Bar");
```

In AutoMapper v8.0+ ResolveUsing has been removed and the docs mention ResolveUsing should be replaced by MapFrom, but in MapFrom the Context or Items don't seem to be known.

What is the V8.0+ method of doing this? The Documentation leaves a lot to be desired on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, x, context) => context.Options.Items["Foo"]));
```